# How to get a ASPxGridview column GroupIndex in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, grouping, aspxgridview

I have got a aspxgridview which I can group columns on , how do I get the column that I have grouped **groupindex** I know how to check if its grouped or not , now I just need to find out at which group level it is on in either 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ?

I have already tried something like this :

```
foreach (GridViewColumn column in ASPxGridView1.VisibleColumns) {
     ASPxLabel1.Text = ASPxGridView1.Columns[column.Caption].Grid.IsGroupRow(column.VisibleIndex).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code shows how to ungroup grouped columns and how to see and/or set the GroupIndex. If the column is grouped then it has a GroupIndex >= 0. If the column is not grouped then it has GroupIndex of -1. GroupIndex is the GroupLevel. A GroupIndex of 0 is at the root level.

```
    void GridView_ClearColumnGroups(ASPxGridView theGridView)
    {
        foreach (GridViewDataColumn gvdc in theGridView.Columns)
        {
            if (gvdc != null && gvdc.GroupIndex >= 0)
            {
                gvdc.GroupIndex = -1;
                gvdc.UnGroup();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the documentation for [GridViewDataColumn.GroupIndex](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebGridViewDataColumn_GroupIndextopic).